# what wrong with the following code ?(in file management in c)

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
main()
{
    FILE *f1,*f2,*f3;
    int number,i;
    printf("content of data file\n\n");
    f1 =fopen("data","w");
    for(i=0;i<20;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&number);
        if(number==-1)
            break;
        putw(number,f1);
    }
    fclose(f1);
    f1=fopen("data","r");
    f2=fopen("odd","w");
    f3=fopen("even","w");
    while((number=getw(f1))!=EOF)
    {
        if(number%2==0)
            putw(number,f3);
        else
        {
            putw(number,f2);
        }
        fclose(f1);
        fclose(f2);
        fclose(f3);
        f2=fopen("odd","r");
        f3=fopen("even","r");
        printf("\n\ncontent of odd file\n\n");
        while((number=getw(f2))!=EOF)
            printf("%4d",number);
        printf("\n\ncontent of even number\n\n");
        while((number=getw(f3))!=EOF)
            printf("%4d",number);
    }
}
```

I understood the whole program , but my compiler is not giving the correct answer, I am  using codeblock. whats wrong in the code , none of the program of file management is working correctly ? Why ?

Comment: What's `getw`? It's not ANSI stuff, I suppose. It can be `getc`.

Comment: @ForceBru, didn't tried to google, huh? ;) It is SUS2 [getw](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/getw.html), but it seem to read `sizeof(int)` bytes from file stream (if it was binary).

Comment: I feel like it would be better to newline separate the numbers and use fgets() or something, getw() sounds really problematic for beginners https://www.thinkage.ca/english/gcos/expl/c/lib/getw.html

Comment: There are many things that are wrong with that code: unclear varnames (`f3`), usage of `getw`, tons of `fopen` / `fclose`, and the main problem: It is unclear what it tries to do.

Comment: `main()` should be `int main()`

Answer (score 1):

You have:

```
while((number=getw(f1))!=EOF)
{
    if(number%2==0)
        putw(number,f3);
    else
    {
        putw(number,f2);
    }
    fclose(f1);
    fclose(f2);
    fclose(f3);
```

That is premature closing of the files. Next call to `getw(f1)` will be a problem -- it's undefined behavior.

And then you have in thee same loop.

```
    f2=fopen("odd","r");
    f3=fopen("even","r");
```

Now `f2` and `f3` cannot be used to write into.

Try:

```
while((number=getw(f1))!=EOF)
{
    if(number%2==0)
        putw(number,f3);
    else
    {
        putw(number,f2);
    }
}

// Now you can safely close the files.
fclose(f1);
fclose(f2);
fclose(f3);

// Reopen the files in read mode to examine their contents.
f2=fopen("odd","r");
f3=fopen("even","r");
```

Answer (score 1):

You mistyped the program.  You typed an extra `{` after the `else` before `putw(number,f2);`

Try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    FILE *f1,*f2,*f3;
    int number,i;
    printf("content of data file\n\n");
    f1 =fopen("data","w");
    for(i=0;i<20;i++) {
        if (scanf("%d",&number) != 1 || number==-1)
            break;
        putw(number,f1);
    }
    fclose(f1);
    f1=fopen("data","r");
    f2=fopen("odd","w");
    f3=fopen("even","w");
    while((number=getw(f1))!=EOF) {
        if(number%2==0)
            putw(number,f3);
        else
            putw(number,f2);
    }
    fclose(f1);
    fclose(f2);
    fclose(f3);
    f2=fopen("odd","r");
    f3=fopen("even","r");
    printf("\n\ncontent of odd file\n\n");
    while((number=getw(f2))!=EOF)
        printf("%4d",number);
    printf("\n\ncontent of even number\n\n");
    while((number=getw(f3))!=EOF)
        printf("%4d",number);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After you read the first thing from `f1`, you close all of your file descriptors, reopen the output files for reading, and print out their contents.  Then you go back to the start of the loop to try to read the second thing from `f1`, but it's closed now.

You probably wanted the `while` loop to complete *before* closing all the files.

Answer (score 0):

The most visible problem is it fclose()ing everything and trying to present the results WITHIN the loop: it should be doing that AFTER it.